# Reading IE css on server

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

i have a wordpress based website and when i was working on localhost, i was using this code to read the css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory()."/ie.css"; ?>" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

As you can see, the second part of the code is to change the css when i'm viewing the site on Internet explorer. It happens this was working perfectly on xampp but now, after migrating por an online server, the second part of the code is not working, the styles are not applyed when i see the online page on IE.

Any hints why this is happening?

Comment: give the same url as you are using in all browser but should be in conditional comment as its already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <?php get_stylesheet_directory() ?>
```

Returns an absolute server path;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory

Change your code to;

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
 <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/ie.css"; ?>" media="screen" type="text/css" />
 <![endif]-->
```

And it should work for you.

Comment: Final result:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/ie.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

Thanks a lot McNab